# Using NumPy's histogram_bin_edges in a Seaborn histogram

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

As the title says I am trying to use the ndarray output of histogram_bin_edges in a Seaborn plot, both for calculations and also making of the plot's descriptions.

The first problem I am facing is this output from `set_xticklabels`, which I assume is a floating-point problem?
[problem1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAjz8.png)

And then using `around` to mitigate it will give me this: [problem2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIX6p.png)

How can I get consistent precision in the output numbers (such as pretty-printing) like 1.00, 2.80, 3.66 etc?

```
# df = pd.DataFrame([3.33])
hist = np.histogram_bin_edges(mydata, bins="sturges")
print(hist)
hist = np.around(hist, decimals=2)
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
x =sns.histplot(mydata, bins=hist, stat="probability", element="poly", fill=False, palette=['orange'], linewidth=2.5)
x.set_xticks(hist)
x.set_xticklabels(hist)
y = sns.histplot(mydata, bins=hist, stat="probability")
plt.legend([],[], frameon=False)
t1 = plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

Comment: Did you upgrade to the latest seaborn / matplotlib versions?

Comment: @JohanC Yes I'm on matplotlip 3.3.3 and seaborn 0.11 which I believe are the latest versions.

Comment: OK.  Did you try without `set_xticklabels(hist)`? Normally `set_xticklabels()` is only needed when you want to the tick labels different from their numerical value. Also, its better to change the ticks after calling the second `sns.histplot` as they both use the same (default) subplot.

Comment: @JohanC Removing the `set_xticklabels` did the job, thank you very much.